# Rails 5 validate foreign key with strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Product model that belongs to a Scope, by having a scope_id.

A User can change the Scope of a Product

A User only has access to a small subset of Scopes. I want to prevent someone from manually inserting a scope_id in a form that he should not be able to select. These scopes are set on login in `session[:scope_ids]`

I was thinking to do this using the strong parameters:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, scope_id: session[:scope_ids])
end
```

However, this does not work. I still get `Unpermitted parameters: scope_id` on submit.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Is your model really called Scope? "Scope" is a reserved word in Rails. That alone will cause you some headaches.

Comment: Can you post the params output from your Rails logfile?